# auth.js:15 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect,

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mern

the react is rendering it infinitly, i dont know how to stop
please say a solution to apply on the attached code below

Error shown in console:
""" **[1836]  auth.js:15 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1045:3)**"""

```
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useContext, createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
    user: null,
    token: "",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem("auth");
    if (data) {
      const parseData = JSON.parse(data);
      setAuth({
        ...auth,
        user: parseData.user,
        token: parseData.token,
      });
    }
  }, [auth]);
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// custom hook
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export { useAuth, AuthProvider };
```

please comment the corrected code

i need to stop the rendering multiple times

Answer (score 0):

- You have added state dependency in useEffect and setState in useEffect that occurred infinite loop.
- Either remove [auth] dependency in useEffect or add condition to don't do again setState after once it is done.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering is likely due to the fact that you're using auth as a dependency in the useEffect inside the AuthProvider component. This creates a circular dependency, as updating auth triggers the useEffect, which updates auth again, leading to an infinite loop.

```
const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const storedAuth = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth")) || {
    user: null,
    token: "",
  };

  // ** First Way
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState({
  user: parseData.user,
  token: parseData.token});

 // ** Second way
 // const [auth, setAuth] = useState({user: null, token:""})
 // useEffect(()=>{setAuth(storedAuth)},[storedAuth])
  
  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

// custom hook
const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);

export { useAuth, AuthProvider };
```

In the **First way**, we directly set the initial state of auth based on the local storage value. We also remove auth from the dependency array of the useEffect to avoid the infinite loop issue.